# FancyBox resizes full size image on first open

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

Im using FancyBox v3.2.10 and the script resizes images to many times its size on first open.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('[data-fancybox="artistpics"]').fancybox({
                autoScale: true,
                protect: true,
                animationEffect : "zoom",
                animationDuration : 300,
                transitionEffect : "slide",
                loop: true,
                margin : [44,0,22,0],
                thumbs : {
                  autoStart : true,
                  axis      : 'y',
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The gallery divs is

```
<div class="dashboard-banner-images">
     <a data-fancybox="artistpics" href="/assets/uploads/elvisavatar_428857324.jpg">
<img src="/assets/uploads/elvisavatar_428857324.jpg">
</a>
<a data-fancybox="artistpics" href="/assets/uploads/elvismain_852894529.jpg"><img src="/assets/uploads/elvismain_852894529.jpg">
</a>    
</div>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: which jQuery version are you using? On which browser you are experiencing this issue?

Comment: @gaetanoM The jQuery version is  v3.1.1 and the browser is Chrome

Comment: As described in the documentation, can you test your sw with jQuery v3.2.1? Thanks. In my tests i don't see any problem. So, if you continue to experience troubles can you describe better your issue?

Comment: Upgrading jQuery to v3.2.x should solve this issue.